# How can I run an exe within a form?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I've searched all over and incorporated this into my code:

```
Process process = new Process();

process.StartInfo.FileName = exePath; //this is a valid path
process.Start();
Thread.Sleep(500);
process.WaitForInputIdle();
SetParent(process.MainWindowHandle, this.Handle);
```

However it starts the program normally in its own window and not inside my main form.

Comment: Is the program a console/text program?

Comment: What kind of exe file you are trying to run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a possible solution [here](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/223777-stand-alone-exe-child-mdi-container).

I have not tested the code.

You need to ensure sure you set IsMdiContainer to true on the parent form.

Here is the implementation:

```
Form child = new Form();

Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFile("c:\\executablefile.exe ");

Type type = asm.GetType("WindowsForm", true, true);

object childform = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

child = (Form)childform;

child.MdiParent = this;

child.Show();
```